# Limitations of Packaging Components in Sparx EA?

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I'm running into what I would say are some limitations with the Packaging Components in Sparx EA.

I use them to aggregate a number of commonly-themed web services in a Package.  To be specific, they are JAX-RS Web Services.  I model the Resource as a Packaging Component and the invokable method of the resource as Components.

1. I created a profile and added stereotypes, etc. as per documentation.  When I use them as an MDG Technology in my model, the stereotypes I created for Components were available, but not the ones for Packaging Components.  That is, my Packaging Component stereotypes aren't offered as an option for Packaging Components I create.
2. I tried to put two Packaging Components on a deployment diagram and connect with a `Uses` Connector to show that the one package of Components invokes the other.  This (to my mind) was a good way to show usage at a higher level than the specific "this component uses that one" (which I model in another diagram as a `Uses` Connector).  But, the only connecting options available for this are `Dependency`,  `Information Flow` and `Trace`.
3. In a deployment diagram, a "Packaging Component" cannot be contained by a "Device".  I can drag a "Component" into the device, the outline highlights and a some type of containment relationship is created.  However, with a "Packaging Component", this containment is not activated.

These observations challenge my understanding that a Packaging Component is "just like component, but has the added benefit of being a package for components as well".

Is that a misunderstanding of Packaging Components ... or a limitation of EA?

Comment: As for 1.: what means not offered? Do you have your own toolbox?

Comment: As for 2._ Which `Uses` connector do expect? I only see one in the Use Case toolbox

Comment: @ThomasKilian 1. Yes, I went through all the steps to create an "MDG Technology".  When I go into the stereotypes for Components, I am offered the Component Stereotypes that I created.  But, not so of the Packaging components.

Comment: @ThomasKilian 2. I suppose it's that one.  I expected the same connector options that I get for plain components, but not being offered that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its a limitation of EA. Packaging components are pretty new, and it is indeed quite possible that it doesn't offer all the features a regular element does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The list might not be complete. Simply type PackagingComponent manually.
2. I guess this connector is heritage as I can not find it in the current Superstructures 2.5. Instead use a dependency and stereotype it with `<<uses>>`. The default quick linker does not offer that directly but you can extend the quick linker with your own connectors.

I have a write-up for MDG here: http://community.sparxsystems.com/tutorials/552-24intro-to-creating-a-mdg-file
ICR whether I used the quick linker in that example (I guess I did) but it's another tricky story good for another set of questions ;-)

Comment: Accepting the answer since #2 worked for me and #1 was answered indirectly by the linked tutorial:  if I open the toolbox for the specific MDG Technology I created, it lets me drop in the Packaging Component with my created stereotype.  I can't chose that stereotype from the properties page of the Packaging Component, though.  I'm going to create a separate question for #3 (thinking I should be able to use a similar approach to #1) re/ what type of relationship is created when a component is dropped inside a node.  I can't find that in the properties page for either the Component or Node.

Comment: Your MDG will always appear in your own toolbox, never in one of those which are already present. Usually there is no relation created when you drop one element into another (though I seem to remember some certain rare case). They are only graphically docked and moved as sub-element (if that option is set and it is possible)

Comment: That other question is  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397752/sparx-ea-what-type-of-relationship-created-when-a-component-is-added-to-a-node