# Sparx EA: What type of relationship created when a Component is added to a Node?

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380734/limitations-of-packaging-components-in-sparx-ea/) (point #3), I asked about getting a Packaging Component recognized as contained by a Node (device or execution environment) on a deployment diagram.

No direct answer.  However, the answers to other points led me toward an alternative that seems simple in concept: manually create the relationship or link.

So, I looked @ one of my `Component <--> Node`  "containment" links to see what Sparx creates in the background.  But, from the properties page / dialog of both the Component and Node, I can't see anything linking the two.

So ... what is actually created when a Component is "dropped into" a Node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment to your previous question: None. When you drop one element over another then this is docked graphically (only if it's significantly smaller). As a side effect (and it's legal for UML) the moved element is also made a sub-element of the one where it has been dropped. (There is some option where you can turn of this behavior but don't ask me where in that options haystack EA has.)

P.S.: It's Tools/Options/Diagram/Behavior/Auto Group... (top left the lowest check mark)

Comment: OK ... so I'll just live with this.  When I drag the Node around on my diagram, the Packaging Component moves with it, so there's some (even if graphic-only) connection.  If no actual relationship is created between a Component and a Node, then it seems the only thing I'm missing with the Packaging Component is the fact that EA "highlights" the Node with a dotted-line outline when moving a Component onto it.  For everything else, looks like it's behaving the same.  Thanks for giving the confidence to just let this be and accept it.  BTW, +1 for "haystack"

Comment: See my PS in the answer

Comment: That option has been checked all along.  Might be why it behaved "as expected" even though I didn't get the visual confirmation.

Comment: I think the default is On. Not sure though since it is kept in the registry even if a new release of EA is installed. Try turning it of and you'll see that dock/move will no longer be performed.

Comment: Turning "Auto Group" off means that neither Component nor Packaging Component moved with the Node, as you predict.  However, the Components still "highlight" a dotted edge around the Node and the Packaging Components don't.  I'm happy leaving it at this  point since (a) the Packaging Components move with the Node even though there is a visual difference when dropping onto Node and (b) you've assured me that there's no "hidden" relationship that exists for Components which needs to be created manually for Packaging Components.  I'm ok calling it an inconsistency in EA behaviour. Thanks!

Comment: Many years ago I coined EAUI (EA Unique Interface). It's still in use and I don't see any tendency to improve it. I could start a diatribe but this comment won't let  me write more than 500 chars...